# SP2016 - Spfx Webpart on SP2016 FP2

Tags: sharepoint-2016, spfx

I tried to build a new Webpart targeting SP16 FP2 & SP Online.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part

When I deploy the Package to my SP16 the App does not show up on my other sites.

In my ULS logs i just have the following errors:

```
Unexpected Exception in SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper::InitializeDataCacheFactory for usage 'DistributedClientSideAppUpdateTimeCache' - Exception 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.     at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.DistributedCaching.SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper.InitializeDataCacheFactory()'.
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you deploy your app reference files somewhere or you are just using workbench?

Comment: I tried both, serving the files locally with "gulp serve" and deployed them to a shared SP library.